# Programatically fire windows 7 touch and gesture events

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, windows-7, multi-touch

Please let me know the answers to the following:

1. Is it possible to programmatically fire the touch and gesture events of Windows 7?
2. Is there any API?
3. Is it possible to fire the event from a computer without touch screen?

I am looking for something implemented or implementable in C# if possible.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to do that ? Do you want to fire the event in your own application, or interact with another app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows 7 pre-beta handed out at PDC 2008, there was an API for injecting gesture input into the input system. However, the API was removed before RTM, and I have it on good authority that this is not a supported scenario for Windows 7.